# Remove table frames in pdf output

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx

I'm using python sphinx to generate our user manuals. For this I have to format a pretty large amount of tables.

In some cases we are using tables in order to neatly align pictures and texts. In the mentioned use case we are trying to find a nice solution to suppress the display of the table frames.

I already tried to use the following:

```
.. tabularcolumns:: lll

+----+-----+-----+
| A  | B   | C   |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Unfortunately there are still two lines on the top and on the bottom. What might be the easiest way to achieve the desired behavior of a table without displaying the frames?

Comment: This sounds like you need to know LaTeX syntax to customize table output, if it is possible. I don't know of any easy or simple option. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

After trying different kind of approaches I stumbled over the following clumsy solution, which is seemingly not the best so far. Imagine that one might have 20 or more tables without frames in a document.

```
.. raw:: latex

   \begingroup
   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}

+----+-----+-----+
| A  | B   | C   |
+----+-----+-----+

.. raw:: latex

   \endgroup
```

Unfortunately, it was the solution I can imagine.

** Revised solution **

It is possible to reduce the pain by defining some substitutions. Just add the following lines to your `conf.py`.

```
rst_epilog = r"""
.. |noFrameStart| raw:: latex

   \begingroup
   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}

.. |noFrameEnd| raw:: latex

   \endgroup
"""
```

No one can easily remove the frame of the table with:

```
|noFrameStart|

    +----+-----+-----+
    | A  | B   | C   |
    +----+-----+-----+

|noFrameEnd|
```

This is probably the shortest solution one might achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the LaTeX-based PDF builder included with Sphinx, you can use the [rinohtype builder](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/quickstart.html#sphinx-builder), which allows for easier [customization of styling](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/elementstyling.html) such as table borders. (Full disclosure: I am rinohtype's author.)

For example, table borders can be suppressed for specific tables like this. In the reStructuredText document, set a custom class *frameless* on your table:

```text
Default (with frames):

+----+-----+-----+
| A  | B   | C   |
+----+-----+-----+


Without frames:

.. table::
   :class: frameless

   +----+-----+-----+
   | A  | B   | C   |
   +----+-----+-----+
```

In the stylesheet, define a selector that identifies any border of the frameless table and set its *stroke* property to *none*.

```ini
[STYLESHEET]
base = sphinx

[frameless table cell border : Table(has_class='frameless') / ... / +TableCellBorder]
stroke = none
```

The `+` increases the priority of this selector so that it wins over any of the [more specific built-in table border selectors](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/0f2725868ec6e3234458a700d3bfec987fee5aca/src/rinoh/stylesheets/matcher.py#L341-L379).

The result:

[image: rinohtype output]

That said, I would advise against using tables for layout purposes like this, regardless of the Sphinx builder used.